# How can I make the list of letters from A to Z and iterate through them in the shell?

Tags: perl, unix, shell, awk, csh

Say I want to iterate from letter A to letter Z in csh shell. How do I succinctly do that?

In bash I would do something like

```
for i in 'A B C ...Z'; do echo $i; done
```

The point is I don't want to write A through Z, I want something like

```
[A-Z]
```

Can you suggest a one line suggestion in AWK or Perl?

Comment: It's "c-shell" not "corn shell". "Korn" shell is another animal entirely.

Comment: In bash: $ for i in {A..Z}; do echo $i; done

Comment: In korn: $ for i in {A..Z}^Jdo^Jecho $i^Jdone

Comment: In bash, you would omit the single quotes around the letters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through alphabets in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7300070/608639).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl

```
$,=" ";print +(A..Z)
```

or to use inside a shell:

```
for i in `perl -e '$,=" ";print +(A..Z)'` ; do echo $i ; done
```

Comment: Why do you have the parens around the range operator? Is there some odd shell interaction that I'm missing?

Comment: I prefer `perl -E'say for A..Z'`

Comment: This doesn't work with 'use strict'.  You need quotes around the A and the Z.  But then strict isn't on by default so I guess thats fine.

Comment: `perl -e '$,=" ";print +(a,b,d..k,"m",t..z)'` works - quotes required around "m" to stop perl interpreting it as the "match" operator.

Comment: In shell: `jot -c 26 A`.

Comment: In shell `sudo bash`, `apt-get install athena-jot ; exit`, `jot -c 26 A` (fixed that for you)

Answer (score 7):

```
perl -e 'print for "a" .. "z", "A" .. "Z", 0 .. 9'
```

Comment: not what I am looking for. With above , you cannot iterate over each letter and do something with it , say mkdir, as you CANNOT access them individually.

Comment: Why can't you iterate over them? The Perl range operator just returns a list. It's a list like any other list. Do whatever you like with it. Furthermore, you need to clarify your question for all the stuff you aren't telling us.

Comment: Because Andrei wants to iterate in the shell.

Answer (score 4):

Hope you have Ruby installed. ;)
See this, plain command-line from the shell:

1. using Ruby to iterate from A to Z and ask to print the letters:

   ```
   $ ruby -e ' "a".upto("z") {|letter| print letter}; print "\n"'
   ```
2. iterate from A to Z and substitute the value obtained during the current iteration into a string, then print the string:

   ```
   $ ruby -e ' "a".upto("z") {|letter| puts "mkdir #{letter}"}'
   ```

   ```
   mkdir a
   mkdir b
   mkdir c
   mkdir d
   ...
   mkdir z
   ```
3. use the output of the iteration from A to C as an argument to `mkdir`, in order to create 3 directories:

   ```
   $ mkdir $(ruby -e ' "a".upto("c") {|letter| puts "#{letter}"}')
   ```

   do a listing to see the results:

   ```
   $ ls -al
   drwxr-xr-x  2 iuliu users  4096 2009-10-07 00:09 a
   drwxr-xr-x  2 iuliu users  4096 2009-10-07 00:09 b
   drwxr-xr-x  2 iuliu users  4096 2009-10-07 00:09 c
   ```

Hope this helps a bit! ;)

regards,
Iuliu

Answer (score 2):

nobody has gawk solution, therefore here's one

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=65;i<=90;i++) printf "%c", i}'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for i in $(perl -e 'for my $i ("a".."z") { print "$i "; }'); do ...; done
```

... or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish?

(Admittedly the suggestion using `$,=" "` is even better than the explicit Perl `for` loop).  However, I don't understand value of wrapping the range in `+()` punctuation.  It works for me if I just use: `print A..Z;` ... though `perl -we 'print a..z;' gives me a warning about unquoted strings, but the uppercase version doesn't.  The statement`print +(a..z)`gives exactly the same warning ... and quoting any of these eliminates the warning.  So what's the intent of the`+(...)`?  Is it just trying to force this into a list context?)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach i (`jot -c 26 65`)
    echo $i
end
```

Comment: ONE liner please, that's 3 lines. so shell complains with 

foreach i ( `jot -c 26 65` ); echo $i; end
jot: Command not found.
foreach?

Comment: You can simply hit enter after foreach var (...) and the shell will let you continue enter lines until you type end

Comment: I guess now I understand the question :D

Comment: jot first appeared in 4.2BSD.  It may not be in non-BSD derived OSes.

Answer (score 0):

**USING AWK:**

You can refer to the ASCII Character Set using the following link:

http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html

Now to iterate through any set of value, you can use the AWK command as follows:

awk 'BEGIN{ for(i=97;i<123;i++){printf "%c ",i}; printf "\n";}'

Result:
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

Here 97 corresponds to letter "a" and 122 is "z". You can vary the result by using any of the value from the list given above.

- 65 to 90 for A to Z
- 48 to 57 for 0 to 9
- 97 to 122 for a to z

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question. The obvious Windows use case is iterating through a list of drive letters. This works in Cygwin:

```bash
for i in a b {d..z}; do (du -s "/cygdrive/$i;"); done
```

Or another example:

```bash
for i in a b {d..h} {r..u}; do df /cygdrive/$i | grep -v Filesystem; done
```

Or yet another example using Perl - thanks to [Jim Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149076/jim-dennis) for [his inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1465097):

```perl
perl -e 'for my $i ("a","b","d".."i","r".."v") { print "$i\n"; }' | sed -e 's/^/\/cygdrive\//'
```