# Looping through alphabets in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I want to `mv` all the files starting with 'x' to directory 'x'; something like:

```
mv path1/x*.ext path2/x
```

and do it for all alphabet letters a, ..., z

How can I write a bash script which makes 'x' loops through the alphabet?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

```
for x in {a..z}
do
    echo "$x"
    mkdir -p path2/${x}
    mv path1/${x}*.ext path2/${x}
done
```

Comment: May I ask why you enclose x with braces on 4th and 5th line?

Comment: It's not required here but well, it works, and makes parameters stand out better;) https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Usually `"$x"` is enough and a better way to make it stand out.

Comment: @WeijunZhou that is a problem if you want to expand variable x followed by the letters 'y' and 'z'. if you try to expand `"$xyz"` the interpreter will think you're trying to print a variable named xyz while `"${x}yz"` will let the interpreter know exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: I meant `"$x"yz`.

Answer (score 48):

This should get you started:

```
for letter in {a..z} ; do
  echo $letter
done
```

Answer (score 28):

here's how to generate the Spanish alphabet using nested brace expansion

```
for l in {{a..n},ñ,{o..z}}; do echo $l ; done | nl
1  a
 ...
14  n
15  ñ
16  o
...
27  z
```

Or simply

```
echo -e {{a..n},ñ,{o..z}}"\n" | nl
```

If you want to generate the [obsolete](http://www.rae.es/consultas/exclusion-de-ch-y-ll-del-abecedario) 29 characters Spanish alphabet

```
echo -e {{a..c},ch,{d..l},ll,{m,n},ñ,{o..z}}"\n" | nl
```

Similar could be done for French alphabet or German alphabet.

Comment: Ugly alternative to avoid splitting the alphabet: `for j in $(for i in $(echo {a..z} ñ ch ll ); do echo $i; done| sort | xargs); do echo "Hello-$j"; done`

Answer (score 5):

With uppercase as well

```
for letter in {{a..z},{A..Z}}; do
  echo $letter
done
```

Answer (score 5):

This question and the answers helped me with my problem, partially.
I needed to *loupe over a **part of the alphabet*** in bash.

Although the expansion [is strictly textual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

[I found a solution:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/464706/edit) and made it even more simple:

```
START=A
STOP=D
for letter in $(eval echo {$START..$STOP}); do
    echo $letter
done
```

Which results in:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Hope its helpful for someone looking for the same problem i had to solve,
and ends up here as well

Comment: depending on which shell you have, this reverse lookup might be useful at times : :::::::::::::::::::::: `printf '%d %d' "'A" "'D"` ::::::  `65 68` (note the apostrophe `'` right front of both `A` and `D`) ::::: for some shells, it also works for `Unicode` chars   ::::: ::::: ::::: ::: ::::: ::::: ::::: ::::: :: ::::: ::::: ::::: ::::: `printf '%s %d' $'\uACDC' "'"$'\uACDC'` :::::: `곜 44252`

Answer (score 4):

Using [`rename`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=rename):

```
mkdir -p path2/{a..z}
rename 's|path1/([a-z])(.*)|path2/$1/$1$2' path1/{a..z}*
```

If you want to strip-off the leading [a-z] character from filename, the updated perlexpr would be:

```
rename 's|path1/([a-z])(.*)|path2/$1/$2' path1/{a..z}*
```

Answer (score 1):

A POSIX compliant version (using AWK):

```bash
for letter in $(awk 'BEGIN { for (i=97; i<123; i++) printf("%c ", i) }')
do
    echo $letter
done
```

Answer (score -4):

[image: Looping through alphabet]
I hope this can help.

for i in {a..z}

for i in {A..Z}

for i in {{a..z},{A..Z}}

use loop according to need.

Comment: That is already covered in other answers. Please don't add duplicates, or explain how yours is better than the previous answers.