# Batch APPEND (RENAME) a specific keyword to set of files

Tags: python, macos, shell, applescript

I have few files namely - "a", "b", "c",etc.. I want to add the keyword: "**.mov**" to all files in that folder.

Please suggest me an approach which script will be best suited for this - AppleScript, Shell, Python etc. (I being a non-scripting guy).

***Note: I m using MacOSX-Maverics[Terminal].***

Comment: This is not a site to write scripts for you. There is also Super User, where there are [plenty of OS X batch rename posts](http://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bosx%5D+batch+rename+is%3Aq) already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)
do
    echo $file
    echo $file.mov
    mv -i $file{,.mov}
done
```

Comment: @haidro [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300070/bash-script-looping-through-alphabet) is the question **I** had asked like 3 years ago; you see the point?

Comment: No I don't actually. That question should have been closed (and is still eligible to be closed)