# Iterate over letters in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

Is it possible to iterate over a list of letters, as followed:

```
aaaa, aaab, ..., aaaz, aaba, aabb, ..., aabz, ..., zzzy, zzzz
```

I know the syntax to iterate over the alphabet:

```
for i in {a..z}
```

but couldn't figure out a way to do the extended version...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through alphabets in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7300070/608639).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}
```

Use it in a loop:

```
for i in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}; do
    echo $i
done
```

It would produce:

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad
aaae
...
zzzv
zzzw
zzzx
zzzy
zzzz
```

You can read more about combining and nesting brace expansions [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace).

Comment: Remember this is printing 26^4 lines though so may take a while and seem like its hung

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BASH doesn't care what is contained in the sequence, as long as you give it the sequence.

```
for i in ducks geese swans; do echo $i; done
ducks
geese
swans
```

for building further with brace expansion, you just need to work on your brace statements:

```
for i in aaa{a..z}; do echo $i; done
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad
aaae
aaaf
aaag
aaah
aaai
aaaj
aaak
...
```

Take a look at brace expansion in man bash. You can use the above to satisfy your needs by a set of nested loops with differing levels of prefix for your expansion setups.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know bash well, but wouldn't that work?

```
// Pseudocode
for i in {a..z}
for j in {a..z}
for k in {a..z}
for l in {a..z}
echo $i$j$k$l
```