# How to loop through the first n letters of the alphabet in bash

Tags: bash, loops

I know that to loop through the alphabet, one can do

```
for c in {a..z};  do   something;  done
```

My question is, how can I loop through the first `n` letters (e.g. to build a string) where `n` is a variable/parameter given in the command line.

I searched SO, and only found answers doing this for numbers, e.g. using C-style `for` loop or `seq` (see e.g. [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash)). And I don't have `seq` in my environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through alphabets in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7300070/608639).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The straightforward way is sticking them in an array and looping over that by index:

```
#!/bin/bash
chars=( {a..z} )
n=3
for ((i=0; i<n; i++))
do
  echo "${chars[i]}"
done
```

Alternatively, if you just want them dash-separated:

```
printf "%s-" "${chars[@]:0:n}"
```

Answer (score 3):

**[that other guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29288523/45375) is probably the way to go**, but here's an **alternative that doesn't require an array variable**:

```
n=3 # sample value

i=0 # var. for counting iterations
for c in {a..z};  do 
  echo $c # do something with "$c"
  (( ++i == n )) && break # exit loop, once desired count has been reached
done
```

@rici points out in a comment that you could make do without aux. variable `$i` by using the conditional `(( n-- )) || break` to exit the loop, but note that this modifies `$n`.

---

Here's another array-free, but less efficient approach that uses **substring extraction (parameter expansion)**:

```
n=3 # sample value

# Create a space-separated list of letters a-z.
# Note that chars={a..z} does NOT work.
chars=$(echo {a..z})

# Extract the substring containing the specified number
# of letters using parameter expansion with an arithmetic expression,
# and loop over them.
# Note:
#  - The variable reference must be _unquoted_ for this to work.
#  - Since the list is space-separated, each entry spans 2 
#    chars., hence `2*n` (you could subtract 1 after, but it'll work either way).
for c in ${chars:0:2*n};  do 
  echo $c # do something with "$c"
done
```

---

Finally, you can **combine the array and list approaches** for concision, although the pure array approach is more efficient:

```
n=3 # sample value

chars=( {a..z} ) # create array of letters

# `${chars[@]:0:n}` returns the first n array elements as a space-separated list
# Again, the variable reference must be _unquoted_.
for c in ${chars[@]:0:n}; do
  echo $c # do something with "$c"
done
```

Comment: Or `((n--))||break` if you were golfing

Comment: @ric:i Indeed, but, generally, I prefer clarity of intent over golfing, but I realize that legibility is in the eye of the beholder. Did my approach strike you (no pun intended) as "golfy" too?

Comment: When I'm aiming for clarity I usually go for `if...then`, but tastes and styles differ. I'd count `n` down in any case, unless I needed `i` for something, but ditto.

Comment: @rici: I hear you. Personally, I love the concision of `&&` and `||`, but I'm aware that it's less of a household idiom than `if ... then ... else`. If we assume that `$n` was passed as an argument, my preference is not to modify it, hence the use of aux. variable `$i`.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the character code of the letters of the alphabet and convert back and forth:

```
# suppose $INPUT is your input
INPUT='x'
# get the character code and increment it by one
INPUT_CHARCODE=`printf %x "'$INPUT"`
let INPUT_CHARCODE++

# start from character code 61 = 'a'
I=61  
while [ $I -ne $INPUT_CHARCODE ]; do
    # convert the index to a letter
    CURRENT_CHAR=`printf "\x$I"`
    echo "current character is: $CURRENT_CHAR"
    let I++
done
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the `printf %x "'<char>"` idiom (and its inverse, `printf  '\x%s' <charCode>`), which is even mandated by POSIX - ["If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote"](http://man.cx/printf), but to solve the OP's problem there really is no need to convert back and forth between characters and their ASCII values.

Comment: Also, I suggest not using all-uppercase variable names, so as to avoid conflicts with _environment_ variables.

Comment: You're welcome and I agree. The array solution is much neater.

Answer (score 1):

Are you only iterating over the alphabet to create a subset?  If that's the case, just make it simple:

```
 $ alpha=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz
 $ n=4
 $ echo ${alpha:0:$n}
 abcd
```

**Edit**. Based on your comment below, do you have `sed`?

```
% sed -e 's/./&-/g' <<< ${alpha:0:$n}
a-b-c-d-
```

Comment: I needed to loop through it. For example, `$ alpha=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz; n=4; for c in  ${alpha:0:$n}; do echo ${c}- ; done` gives me `abcd-`. But I needed `a-b-c-d-`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, indeed `sed` works for my case above:) I need to assemble a more complex string than inserting delim's though. I suspect a real loop is needed.

Comment: In bash, there isn't a need to include the `$` on `n` within the substring index expression `${alpha:0:n}` works fine (similar to `((...))` syntax).

Answer (score 0):

This question and the answers helped me with my problem, partially.
I needed to *loupe over a part of the alphabet **based on a letter*** in bash.

Although the expansion [is strictly textual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

[I found a solution:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/464706/edit) and made it even more simple:

```
START=A
STOP=D
for letter in $(eval echo {$START..$STOP}); do
    echo $letter
done
```

Which results in:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Hope it's helpful for someone looking for the same problem i had to solve,
and ends up here as well

([also answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300070/looping-through-alphabets-in-bash/60561527#60561527))

And **the complete answer to the original question** is:

```
START=A
n=4

OFFSET=$( expr $(printf "%x" \'$START) + $n)
STOP=$(printf "\x$OFFSET") 

for letter in $(eval echo {$START..$STOP}); do
    echo $letter
done
```

Which results in the same:

```
A
B
C
D
```