# How to find drive letter for portable git-bash

Tags: windows, git-bash

I run git-bash in windows Portably on a usb drive. Some of the time the drive letter is E and sometimes it is F.

up until recently it had always been F and I'd used aliases such as:

```
alias subl='"/f/Sublime Text Build 3047/sublime_text.exe"'
```

in my .bashrc file. Is there a way to find the drive letter and substitute it in so I end up with something like:

```
alias subl='"/DRIVELETTER/Sublime Text Build 3047/sublime_text.exe"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, don't forget that with Windows, you can [assign a *permanent* driver letter to an USB key](https://www.howtogeek.com/96298/assign-a-static-drive-letter-to-a-usb-drive-in-windows-7/) (or any drive for that matter).

If not, since there is no `/mnt` in the Git bash on Windows, you would need to add in your bashrc a [loop on the potential drive letter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7300107/6309), looking for a known file in your usb key.

```
for letter in {a..z} ; do
  if [[ -e /${letter}/afile ]]; then
    export DRIVELETTER=${letter}
    break
  fi
done
```